# datepicker onselect is not firing From gridmvc.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
dateContainer.datepicker({
    defaultDate: this.filterValue,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yyyy',
    onSelect: function (dateText, t) {
        var type = $context.container.find(".grid-filter-type").val();
        $context.cb(type, dateText);
    }
});
```

I'm using gridmvc.js and bootstrap-datepicker.js plugin.
OnSelect event is not firing anyway. I don't know what is the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know because of what, the problem is occurred. But I've found the temporary solution for this. For the solution, you've to change one line of code in bootstrap-datepicker.js. (Check about the license before you change and use the plugin)

```
case 'span':
                        if (!target.is('.disabled')) {
                            this.viewDate.setUTCDate(1);
                            if (target.is('.month')) {
                                var day = 1;
                                var month = target.parent().find('span').index(target);
                                var year = this.viewDate.getUTCFullYear();
                                this.viewDate.setUTCMonth(month);
                                this._trigger('changeMonth', this.viewDate);
                                if (this.o.minViewMode === 1) {
                                    this._setDate(UTCDate(year, month, day,0,0,0,0));
                                }
                            } else {
                                var year = parseInt(target.text(), 10)||0;
                                var day = 1;
                                var month = 0;
                                this.viewDate.setUTCFullYear(year);
                                this._trigger('changeYear', this.viewDate);
                                if (this.o.minViewMode === 2) {
                                    this._setDate(UTCDate(year, month, day,0,0,0,0));
                                }
                            }
                            this.showMode(-1); this.fill();
```

Here the problem is occured because of this.fill() is called.

if you comment this line in plugin, datepicker won't hide any way on month and year change. Or you can change by following,

```
if (target.is('.month')) {
                                if (!this._o.changeMonth) {
                                    this.fill();
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                if (!this._o.changeYear) {
                                    this.fill();
                                }
                            }
```

Then this will work, based on the parameter you've given while creating datepicker.